# How to pass Initialized Array as OUT parameter to COM call

Tags: python, com, parameter-passing, python-3.6, comtypes

I have a commercial package which has a COM interface. I am trying to control it via the COM interface from Python. Most things are working just fine with regular input parameters and outputs.

However one particular set of functions appear to take a pre-allocated data structure as input which they will then fill out with the results of the query. So: an out-parameter of type array in this instance.

Some helpful example VBA code which accompanies the product alongside an Excel spreadsheet seems to work just fine. It declares the input array as: `Dim myArray(customsize) as Integer`

This then gets passed directly into the call on the COM object: `cominterface.GetContent(myArray)`

However when I try something similar in Python, I either get errors or no results depending on how I try to pass the array in:

```
import comtypes
... code to generate bindings, create object, grab the interface ...

# create an array for storing the results
my_array_type = c_ulong * 1000
my_array_instance = my_array_type ()

# attempt to pass the array into the call on the COM interface
r = cominterface.GetContent(my_array_instance )

# expect to see id's 1,2,3,4
print(my_array_instance)
```

The above gives me error:

```
TypeError: Cannot put <__main__.c_ulong_Array_1000 object at 0x00000282514F5640> in VARIANT
```

So it would seem that the comtypes does not support ctype arrays for passing through as it tries to make it a VARIANT.

Thus a different attempt:

```
# create an array for storing the results
my_array_instance = [0] * 100

# attempt to pass the array into the call on the COM interface
r = cominterface.GetContent(my_array_instance )

# expect to see id's 1,2,3,4
print(my_array_instance)
```

The above call has a return code indicating success, but the array is unchanged  and still contains the initial 0's it was preseaded with.

So I am *assuming* here that comtypes is somehow not transporting the written values back into the Python list. But thats a big assumption - I really don't know.

I have tried a number of things including using POINTER, byref() and various things. Almost everything results in some kind of error - either in the code doing the bindings or an error from the COM function I am calling to say the parameter does not meet its requirements.

If someone knows how I can pass in a pre-allocated array for this COM function to write to, I would be very much appreciative.

EDIT:

I rewrote the code in C# and it had the same problem, so I began to suspect the COM interface was not correct. By providing my own interface with modified function signatures (adding a 'ref' for the parameters), I was able to get the calls to work.

I suspect the tlb file was in error and happened to work with VBA, but I am unsure.

Comment: Since it's a byref (in/out) argument, you're supposed to create a VARIANT beforehand, so using comtypes.automation I believe, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345405/com-object-variant-parameters-in-comtypes-python

Comment: @SimonMourier I've tried that too. I've tried making the variants prior, and inspecting them after. I even tried an array of variants instead of a variant constructed from an array. I either get errors from the call to the COM interface or a success code but no data in the array that I can find.

Comment: difficult to help w/o being able to reproduce.